# How to upgrade util-linux from 2.32.1 to 2.34 in Redhat

Tags: linux, terminal, redhat

Is there a way to upgrade package util-linux 2.32.1 to version 2.34 on RHEL 8.5.
Version 2.34 has many more output columns available for lsblk compared to 2.32.1 that I would like to use.

Searching the repo shows I have the latest.

```
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Last metadata expiration check: 2:29:02 ago on Mon 16 May 2022 06:44:33 PM EDT.
Installed Packages
util-linux.x86_64                     2.32.1-35.el8                     @rhel-8-for-x86_64-baseos-rpms
Available Packages
util-linux.x86_64                     2.32.1-8.el8                      rhel-8-for-x86_64-baseos-rpms 
util-linux.x86_64                     2.32.1-17.el8                     rhel-8-for-x86_64-baseos-rpms 
util-linux.x86_64                     2.32.1-22.el8                     rhel-8-for-x86_64-baseos-rpms 
util-linux.x86_64                     2.32.1-24.el8                     rhel-8-for-x86_64-baseos-rpms 
util-linux.x86_64                     2.32.1-27.el8                     rhel-8-for-x86_64-baseos-rpms 
util-linux.x86_64                     2.32.1-28.el8                     rhel-8-for-x86_64-baseos-rpms 
util-linux.x86_64                     2.32.1-35.el8                     rhel-8-for-x86_64-baseos-rpms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to clone this repo `https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux.git`

Then follow this how-to found here.

`https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux/blob/next/Documentation/howto-compilation.txt`

```
lsblk --version
lsblk from util-linux 2.38.141-581b1
```

Comment: New link is https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux/blob/master/Documentation/howto-compilation.txt